# AngularJS module dependencies - clarification?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been investigating the tutorial example from AngularJs's site ( [**this one**](http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-11/app/#/phones))

*(The [main html is pretty empty](http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-11/app/#/phones) (except for `ng-view` and `ng-app=phonecatApp`))*

The `app.js` file includes this :

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'phonecatControllers',
  'phonecatFilters',
  'phonecatServices'
]);

phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider',...
```

Ok, so we have `phonecatApp` module with many dependencies.

But then I saw the `controller.js` file ( they opened a new module for the controllers)

```
/*1*/   var phonecatControllers = angular.module('phonecatControllers', []);
/*2*/   
/*3*/   phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'Phone',
/*4*/     function($scope, $routeParams, Phone) {
/*5*/       ...
/*6*/       });
/*7*/   
/*8*/     }]);
```

`Phone` is a service. ( which is on *another* module , different js file)

**Question**

In line #3 , how does it know what is the `Phone` parameter ? they didnt add any dependecy module in line #1 !
Same for the `$routeParams` , how does it know it ? they **didn't** add any dependency in line #1 to the `ngRoute` !

Am I missing something here ?

Comment: What does the declaration of `Phone` look like?  Is this service registered to `phoncatControllers` module? If not, it does seem strange.

Comment: @DavinTryon http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-11/app/js/services.js

Comment: Ok, I think the assumption made in this example is that `phonecatControllers` will always be registered as a dependency with `phonecatServices`.  Not a great assumption to make when creating independent modules for reuse.  Since, there is only a single `$injector` in the app, this works, but I wouldn't say it is a great way to split modules.

Comment: @DavinTryon So, I can use every module parameter if it is as a dependncy in the main module ?

Comment: I think the angular application has a [single $injector service](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/docs/guide/di), which means all dependent modules put their dependencies in the same injector. This would mean that if A depends on B, and C, then B can use components in C using the same injector service, once A has forced the loading of all of them.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo Exactly what i wanted to know , can u please reference me to the relevant info at the docs ? (couldnt find it) - ?{ this exact issue link please}

Comment: @RoyiNamir I do not have a specific reference for that, but the `$injector` is [a service of the auto module](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/docs/api/AUTO.$injector) and in angular, [services are singletons](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/docs/guide/dev_guide.services.understanding_services). So, I kind of figured it out because of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependency injection works by default for every component of Angular.

This is because every component is defined inside the `angular` object, so it can track it all.

You can check this http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di out to understand how it works.

Comment: So If I add module dependency at the main ng-app  , it allow me to inject it everywhere without writing the dependency ?

Comment: Yes, you only need to define the component in your module (controller, service, constant...), load the module and inject what you want where you want

Comment: **If so**  why [here](http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-11/app/js/services.js) they  added ngResource there ant not in the app.js file under the main module (http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-11/app/js/app.js) ?

Comment: Also  `Phone` is **not** a member of `phonecatControllers`, it is a member of `phonecatServices`

Comment: I thinks it's because the author wants to follow a module design pattern. Every piece of code it's a separate module with its own dependencies. However, in applications I've seen (and made), all depencencies are loaded in the main.js file

Comment: So, I can use every module parameter if it is as a dependncy in the main module?

Comment: phonecatControllers, phonecatServices and phonecatFilters are all loaded in the same module (app): phonecatApp. So, inside the phonecatApp context you can use all those submodules wherever you want

Comment: Yes, every component you define inside the module context is injectable throw the whole module hierarchy :)

Answer (score 7):

This citation from Pawel Kozlowski' [book](http://www.packtpub.com/angularjs-web-application-development/book) seems to be relevant:

> A service defined in one of the application's modules is visible to
>   all the  other modules. In other words, hierarchy of modules doesn't
>   influence  services' visibility to other modules. When AngularJS
>   bootstraps an  application, it combines all the services defined
>   across all the modules  into one application, that is, global
>   namespace.

Comment: Does that mean, that a service/factory etc. must be defined in at least one **module** to become visible for all other modules and components on sub-module level?

Comment: @malte sorry, i'm not sure i understand you correctly, how can it be defined not in a module?

Comment: Oh yeah, my fault. _defined_, not _included_

e.g. including d3 just in the controller, not in the module:

`angular.module("widgets.D3Widget", ['underscore'])

.controller("widgets.D3Widget.D3WidgetCtrl", [
  "$scope",
  "d3",
  function(
    $scope,
    d3
  ) {

   console.log(d3.select('body'));

   //work goes here
  }
]);`

So I still don't understand Angular's dependency technology ...