# Are Angular services available globally?

Tags: angularjs

I have an angularjs application that contains two modules. On one of the modules I have a factory that defines "UserService" on the other module I just have a controller like so

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', 'UserService', function ( $scope, $userService ) {
    alert("HOME");
    console.log("HOME PAGE HERE", $userService);
}]);
```

User service works here even though it's defined on another module that is not injected this module, but I could not find anything that says that is how it is supposed to work. Or maybe I missed something.

Comment: Maybe you are still injecting the two modules into your `ng-app` module somewhere. Can you post your code?

Comment: I think I might see whats going on, if I inject the Home module into the module containing the service, then the home module has access to the parent modules services. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes , take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955886/angularjs-module-dependencies-clarification/21958235#21958235

Comment: Exactly, that's because Angular modules aren't fully independent from each other but "come together" on the global AngularJS object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. In Angular, the module dependency chain just handles the load order of modules. The services registered by modules are available to all other services regardless of the module hierarchy.

In [this plunkr demo,](http://plnkr.co/edit/fZgDMTVYsjpA8lRkkPhA?p=preview) the top level module takes in two dependancies. The `moduleWithController` is able to utilize the `greeter` service, even though this module did not take in the service's module as a dependency. (*I agree is seems as if `moduleWithController` should have to take `moduleWithService` as a dependency to see its service, but that is not how it works.*)

```
  angular.module('moduleWithService', [])
    .value('greeter', {
      greet: 'Hello'
    });

  angular.module('moduleWithController', [])
    .controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'greeter',
      function($scope, greeter) {
        $scope.greeting = "Greeting " + greeter.greet;
      }
    ]);

  angular.module('topModule', ['moduleWithService', 'moduleWithController']);
```