# AngularJS dependencies: constant / controller etc. not loaded in a module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I've stumbled upon [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955886/angularjs-module-dependencies-clarification) by looking for the reason, that a well defined factory is not loaded. Then I wondered about the terms "defined in an angular module".

If I have kind of a service like this:

```
angular.module('d3', ['underscore'])
       .factory('d3', ['$window', 'underscore',
       function($window, _) {
           if (!_.isObject($window.d3)) {
               throw "services.d3: moment library missing!";
           } else {
               return $window.d3;
          }
       }
   ]);
```

And when I try to load this service in a module like this:

```
angular.module("widgets.D3Widget", ['underscore'])

.controller("widgets.D3Widget.D3WidgetCtrl", [
    "$scope",
    "d3",
    function(
        $scope,
        d3
    ) {
        console.log(d3.select('body'));
        //work goes here
    }
]);
```

the service is not loaded. I rather get an Angular error like: *"Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: d3Provider <- d3*.

I've read the Angular docu about DI, but that didn't help very much.

So what is meant by 'defining the service'? Writing the module d3 seems not to be enough, I need to add it in a second **module**, like `angular.module("widgets.D3Widget", ['underscore', 'd3'])`, not just in a component of a module (controller, directive, whatever). Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, cannot post comments. You need to add the 'd3' dependency when configuring module widgets.D3Widget, like this

```js
angular.module("widgets.D3Widget", ['d3'])
```

This is because 'd3' is not residing under the same module as your 'widgets.D3Widget'.

Comment: Alright, so if I have a _component_ of a module and I want to use it in another module, I need to add it **in at least one** other module, right?